# MySQL - Count number of relating rows over multiple tables

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, mariadb

I am making a "quiz app". Each quiz have multiple questions (quizComponents), and each question has multiple answer options (quizComponentOptions) that the participant can select from. The answers are save in the quizResults table. I have these tables:

- Quiz( quizID, quizTitle );
- QuizComponents( componentId, quizID, quizQuestion );
- QuizComponentOptions( optionId, componentId, optionValue );
- QuizResults( resultId, personId, answerOptionId, componentId );
- CorrectOptions( componentId, optionId );

I would like to get a list of all quizes, with a total number of components in each quiz, and also number of correct / incorrect answers in each quiz for any given personId.
Something like:

```
quizTitle   total_quiz_components   correct_answers     incorrect_answers   
"Quiz 1"            3                       2                   1
"Quiz 2"            10                      1                   9
```

The following query gives me all rows in Quiz, with the total number of quiz components every quiz contains.

```
SELECT q.quizTitle, count(qc.componentId) AS total_quiz_components FROM Quiz q
    LEFT JOIN QuizComponents qc ON qc.quizId=q.quizId
        GROUP BY q.quizId;
```

But then I'm stuck in this relations madness.

Answer (score 2):

you need `case based aggregation` to get the correct and incorrect answers.

```
SELECT q.quizTitle, 
       count(qc.componentId) AS total_quiz_components ,
       sum ( case when CO.optionId = QR.answerOptionId then 1 else 0 end) as correct_answers,
       sum ( case when CO.optionId <> QR.answerOptionId then 1 else 0 end) as incorrect_answers,
FROM Quiz q
LEFT JOIN QuizComponents qc ON qc.quizId=q.quizId
LEFT JOIN QuizResults QR on 
QR.componentId = QC.componentId
LEFT JOIN CorrectOptions CO
on CO.componentId = QR.componentId
GROUP BY q.quizTitle;
```